# Is there anyway i can run the same Whatsapp account on both my android phone and android tablet at the same time?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a Samsung J6 phone, with Whatsapp installed.

I also have a Samsung Tablet, Tab A 2019.

Both are running the latest version of Android at the time of writing.

Ive downloaded and setup Whatsapp on the tablet, but this disassociates Whatsapp on my phone, is there anyway i can run the same Whatsapp account on both my android phone and android tablet ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way indeed.
 Install WhatsApp primarily on one of your devices. On another device, open google chrome and head to web.whatsapp.com. Now click the menu icon (on the top right of browser with 3 vertical dots), scroll down and check the "Request desktop site" option. Now you will receive the web version of WhatsApp on one of your devices. Scan the QR Code from your primary device.

Enjoy!